# Why is a[:]=1 fundamentally different to a[:]='1'?

Tags: python

Please consider the two snippets of code (notice the distinction between string and integer):

```
a = []
a[:] = '1'
```

and

```
a = []
a[:] = 1
```

In the first case `a` is `['1']`. In the second, I get the error `TypeError: can only assign an iterable`. Why would using `'1'` over `1` be fundamentally different here?

Comment: Do the quotes mean anything to you?  Could you include the words "String" and "Integer" in your question to clarify the distinction between `'1'` and `1`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Assigning to a slice requires an iterable on the right-hand side.**

`'1'` is iterable, while `1` is not. Consider the following:

```
In [7]: a=[]

In [8]: a[:]='abc'
```

The result is:

```
In [9]: a
Out[9]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

As you can see, the list gets *each character* of the string as a separate item. This is a consequence of the fact that iterating over a string yields its characters.

If you want to replace a range of `a`'s elements with a single scalar, simply wrap the scalar in an iterable of some sort:

```
In [11]: a[:]=(1,) # single-element tuple

In [12]: a
Out[12]: [1]
```

This also applies to strings (provided the string is to be treated as a single item and not as a sequence of characters):

```
In [17]: a[:]=('abc',)

In [18]: a
Out[18]: ['abc']
```

Comment: You could also omit the brackets: `a[:] = 1,` works just as fine. Alhough it is less verbose I suppose.

Comment: @TyrantWave I think you meant *parens*, not brackets. And for other users, parens are not tuple constructors, the comma is. See http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#more-about-tuples

Comment: @Edwin: "Brackets" is correct to people outside the US: http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/C/Commonwealth-Hackish.html. I make a point to prefer "brackets" to "parens", precisely because I'm proud to be a New Zealander (and, more specifically, not American).

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young Cool, I didn't even know about that. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

`'1'` is a string, but it is iterable. It is like a list of characters. `a[:]='1'` replaces the contents of the list `a` with the content of the string `'1'`. But `1` is an integer.

Python does not change the type.

Example:

```
print bool(1=='1') # --> False
```